Reducing image size to 200kb before uploading using javascript is not working
I want to reduce image size to 200kb before uploading that image to server. I am having 5 different inputs for selecting 5 files. I tried using the following code, but still no luck. My images are still getting uploaded as it is (with original size). Kindly help me out. Thanks.
Here is my code that I tried so far:
<div class="col-sm-6">  
<label class="form-label"><strong>ID Proof Front Photo:</strong></label>
<img src="" alt="No Image" id="img1" style='height:150px; display:none;'>                       
<button type="button" id="uploadFrontID" class="registerBtn" onblur="validateIDCardType(), validateFileTypeFront()" onclick="validateIDCardType(), selectFile('frontIDProof')"><img width="35" height="24" src="<?php echo $url; ?>assets/images/id1.svg">  <strong>Select Photo</strong></button>
<input type='file' id="frontIDProof" name="uploadIDFrontPhoto" onchange="readURL1(this)"  style="display:none" accept="image/*" required />
<span id="photoFrontSpan" class="errSpan"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">  
<label class="form-label"><strong>ID Proof Back Photo:</strong></label>
<img src="" alt="No Image" id="img2" style='height:150px; display:none;'>
<button type="button" id="uploadBackID" class="registerBtn" onblur="validateFrontID(), validateIDCardType(), validateFileTypeBack()" onclick=" validateIDCardType(), selectFile('backIDProof')"><img width="35" height="24" src="<?php echo $url; ?>assets/images/id2.svg">  <strong>Select Photo</strong></button>
<input type='file' id="backIDProof" name="uploadIDBackPhoto" style="display:none" onchange="readURL2(this)" accept="image/*" required />
<span id="photoBackSpan" class="errSpan"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">  
<label class="form-label"><strong>Profile Photo 1:</strong></label>
<img src="" alt="No Image" id="img3" style='height:150px; display:none;'>                           
<button type="button" id="profilePhoto1" class="registerBtn" onblur=" validateProfilePhoto1FileType()" onclick="selectFile('profilePhotoFile1')"><img width="24" height="24" src="<?php echo $url; ?>assets/images/photo1.svg">  <strong>Select Photo</strong></button>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL3(this)" id="profilePhotoFile1" name="uploadPhoto1" style="display:none" accept="image/*" required />
<span id="photoSpan1" class="errSpan"></span>                                   
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">  
<label class="form-label"><strong>Profile Photo 2:</strong></label>
<img src="" alt="No Image" id="img4" style='height:150px; display:none;'>                           
<button type="button" id="profilePhoto2" class="registerBtn" onblur="validateProfilePhoto2FileType()" onclick="selectFile('profilePhotoFile2')"><img width="24" height="24" src="<?php echo $url; ?>assets/images/photo2.svg">  <strong>Select Photo</strong></button>
<input type='file' id="profilePhotoFile2" onchange="readURL4(this)" name="uploadPhoto2" style="display:none" accept="image/*"/>
<span id="photoSpan2" class="errSpan"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">  
<label class="form-label"><strong>Profile Photo 3:</strong></label>
<img src="" alt="No Image" id="img5" style='height:150px; display:none;'>                           
<button type="button" id="profilePhoto3" class="registerBtn" onblur="validateProfilePhoto3FileType()" onclick="selectFile('profilePhotoFile3')"><img width="24" height="24" src="<?php echo $url; ?>assets/images/photo3.svg">  <strong>Select Photo</strong></button>
<input type='file' id="profilePhotoFile3" name="uploadPhoto3" onchange="readURL5(this)" style="display:none" accept="image/*"/>
<span id="photoSpan3" class="errSpan"></span>
</div>

  <script>
  //Image resize code starts

        function selectFile(inputId) {
            document.getElementById(inputId).click();
        }
        
        function compressImage(file, maxSizeKB, callback) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                const img = new Image();
                img.onload = function() {
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    
                    // Set the canvas dimensions to the image dimensions
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    
                    // Draw the image on the canvas
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    
                    let compressedFile;
                    let scaleFactor = 0.9; // Initial scale factor
                    
                    do {
                        // Compress the image as JPEG by default
                        let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
                        
                        // If the file type is PNG, compress as PNG format
                        if (file.type === 'image/png') {
                            const pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                            
                            // Check if the PNG version is smaller than the JPEG version
                            if (pngDataUrl.length < dataUrl.length) {
                                dataUrl = pngDataUrl;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // Calculate the file size
                        const fileSizeKB = Math.round(dataUrl.length / 1024);
                        
                        // Check if the file size is within the desired range
                        if (fileSizeKB <= maxSizeKB) {
                            compressedFile = dataUrl;
                            break;
                        }
                        
                        // Reduce dimensions for further compression
                        scaleFactor *= 0.9; // Reduce dimensions by 10%
                        
                        // Adjust canvas dimensions
                        canvas.width *= scaleFactor;
                        canvas.height *= scaleFactor;
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    } while (scaleFactor > 0.1); // Stop when scale factor is too low
                    
                    // Callback with the compressed image
                    callback(compressedFile);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        
        // Example usage:
        function handleFileInput(inputId, event) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const maxSizeKB = 200; // Maximum file size in KB
            
            // Compress the file
            compressImage(file, maxSizeKB, function(compressedFile) {
                // Do something with the compressed file, like displaying it
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = compressedFile;
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            });
        }
        
        // Add onchange event listeners to file inputs
        document.getElementById('frontIDProof').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            handleFileInput('frontIDProof', event);
        });
        document.getElementById('backIDProof').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            handleFileInput('backIDProof', event);
        });
        document.getElementById('profilePhotoFile1').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            handleFileInput('profilePhotoFile1', event);
        });
        document.getElementById('profilePhotoFile2').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            handleFileInput('profilePhotoFile2', event);
        });
        document.getElementById('profilePhotoFile3').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            handleFileInput('profilePhotoFile3', event);
        });
  
  //Image resize code ends  
  
  function readURL1(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#img1").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById("img1").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  
    function readURL2(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#img2").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById("img2").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  
    function readURL3(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#img3").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById("img3").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  
    function readURL4(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#img4").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById("img4").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  
    function readURL5(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#img5").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById("img5").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  
    function enableDisableButton() {
    if (document.getElementById('terms').checked == 0) {
      document.getElementById('regBtn').disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('regBtn').disabled = false;
    }
  }
  
  </script>


How do you upload the files? Do you have a form?

Yes. All the data is getting saved successfully and the file is moving to some folder with the same original size as at the time of attaching to the form. My goal is to reduce down the file size.

You include both HTML and JavaScript in you question -- that is good, but we still need to know how the form is submitted to the server. Do you just submit the form as it is or do you do some kind of AJAX request using JavaScript to post the data? Add that info/code to your question as well.

I am submitting the form as it is. There is no any Ajax call.

While searching for this I came across this example:
    const compressImage = async (file, { quality = 1, type = file.type }) => {
        // Get as image data
        const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(file);

        // Draw to canvas
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = imageBitmap.width;
        canvas.height = imageBitmap.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);

        // Turn into Blob
        const blob = await new Promise((resolve) =>
            canvas.toBlob(resolve, type, quality)
        );

        // Turn Blob into File
        return new File([blob], file.name, {
            type: blob.type,
        });
    };

    // Get the selected file from the file input
    const input = document.querySelector('.my-image-field');
    input.addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
        // Get the files
        const { files } = e.target;

        // No files selected
        if (!files.length) return;

        // We'll store the files in this data transfer object
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

        // For every file in the files list
        for (const file of files) {
            // We don't have to compress files that aren't images
            if (!file.type.startsWith('image')) {
                // Ignore this file, but do add it to our result
                dataTransfer.items.add(file);
                continue;
            }

            // We compress the file by 50%
            const compressedFile = await compressImage(file, {
                quality: 0.5,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
            });

            // Save back the compressed file instead of the original file
            dataTransfer.items.add(compressedFile);
        }

        // Set value of the file input to our new files list
        e.target.files = dataTransfer.files;
    });

https://pqina.nl/blog/compress-image-before-upload/
This compresses an image upon the change event of an input of a certain class. You could replace compressImage with yours, ensure that everything is compatible, changing the parameterization of the call for compressImage and ensuring that you properly handle the return of the function and then whenever a file would be chosen for such an input, it would be automatically compressed, so by the time your form is submitted it will already pick up the compressed file instead of the raw original.
You also do a lot of code duplication, like
    function readURL5(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#img5").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById("img5").style.display = "block";
    }
  }

instead of which you could have
    function readURL(input, id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) { 
        document.querySelector("#" + id).setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
  }

and then call it like readURL(this, "img5") and then you could have a single readURL function instead of 5 which will help you a lot in the long run.
@chrwahl correctly points out in the comment-section that

the DataTransfer object is the only object that implements the FileList interface and at the same time has methods for adding elements/files. The point here is that the file property of the input element hold the compressed images: e.target.files = dataTransfer.files;. I was about to make the same answer...

One can read further about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer

You can add to this that the DataTransfer object is the only object that implements the FileList interface and at the same time has methods for adding elements/files. The point here is that the file property of the input element hold the compressed images: e.target.files = dataTransfer.files;. I was about to make the same answer...

Thanks for the answer @Lajos Arpad. This can also work. But my requirement is to reduce down the image size to 200kb size and keep reducing the image size unless and until it becomes 200kb.

Thanks @chrwahl for looking in to the question.

@PurushottamPatil yes, indeed. You can replace compressImage from the example I have given with yours to have the behavior of repeatedly compressing until the size of the image fits into the bounds.
